# How to read a text file containing NUL characters?

Tags: r, nul

I have a file that contains `NUL` characters.

This file is generated by another program I have no control over, but I have to read it in order to get some crucial information.

Unfortunately, `readChar()` truncates the output with this warning:

> ```
> In readChar("output.txt", 1e+05) :   
>   truncating string with embedded nuls
> ```

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By convention, a text file *cannot* contain non-printable characters (including NUL). If a file contains such characters, it isn’t a text file — it’s a *binary* file.

R strictly<sup>1</sup> adheres to this convention, and completely disallows NUL characters. You really need to read and treat the data as binary data. This means using `readBin` and the `raw` data type:

```
n = file.size(filename)
buffer = readBin(filename, 'raw', n = n)
# Unfortunately the above has a race condition, so check that the size hasn’t changed!
stopifnot(n == file.size(filename))
```

Now we can fix the buffer by removing embedded zero bytes. This assumes UTF-*x* or ASCII encoding! Other encodings might have embedded zero bytes that need to be interpreted!

```
buffer = buffer[buffer != 0L]
text = rawToChar(buffer)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Maybe *too* strictly …

Comment: Note that, for very large files, reading the entire file at once using `readBin` might not be a great idea. In that case, it’s probably a better idea to work with a fixed-sized buffer of a few MiB, process data in batches, and write the sanitised data back to disk into a text file.